413 request entity too large with SharePoint
I'm having a problem with a request from a client (Request Entity Too Large)
It's a Sharepoint solution developed in C# and the front end in Angular.
I've already configured my IIS server to increase the size of the Request Filtering Limits to 52428800
I've also modified uploadReadAheadSize="10485760’
and I've also added to my web.config
but I still get the error returned by my client 413 Request Entity Too Large.
I don't understand why
I've already configured my IIS server to increase the size of the Request Filtering Limits to 52428800
I've also modified uploadReadAheadSize="10485760’
and I've also added to my web.config

Please enable Failed Request Tracing to see what module blocks the requests? Keep in mind a lot can be there, so dig one step further is the key.

Sharepoint has settings to control, per api, the allowed message sizes. But your question does not mention what you are trying to do. Which API/request are you trying to perform ?

Apart from setting the value of uploadReadAheadSize and maxAllowedContentLength, the maxRequestLength also need to be configured. You need to modify all these three values, otherwise the error 413 Request Entity Too Large still exists.
Please follow these steps to configure IIS and the specific input values should be adjusted according to your actual situation.

uploadReadAheadSize



maxAllowedContentLength



maxRequestLength



Thinks for your reply,
I forgot to mention it but yes, I've already configured this one too (maxRequestLength)

Try to update binding in web service's web.config, you can refer to this case.

thanks for the reply, but unfortunately for me nothing has changed...

I suggest you check the IIS logs or SharePoint server's logs for more information.
